# Unable to add logs in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have 2 powershell files. File A is the main file which has a switch case for user and File B has the functions, which are invoked as per user's choice from File A.

Now, for logs, I am adding details to a string variable in File B. When all the process of chosen user option is complete, I am creating a new text file and adding the log detail to it, via powershell File A.

Here I am facing issue as every time the log file is found to be blank. Somehow when the scope changes from powershell file B to A, the log detail variable goes blank. (See image if available.)
Eg. when in option 2, after executing func A, the scope changes to File B to process func C. Here the log variable goes blank.

[image]

Comment: "I am adding details to a string variable in File B" - in the root of File B, or inside the functions? This would be a lot easier if you would just post your code :)

Comment: Inside the functions. Sorry cannot post code due to security issues.

Comment: Are you dot-sourcing File B (the one with the functions) inside File A? Please show us your files with all sensitive data obscured

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make the log variable a global variable:
$global:variableName= "Value"

Comment: In which file? Does global variables retain data when scope changes between files?

Comment: You could declare it in your main file. Yes, values are retained between files.